# FlickrNet Get Photos From Albums

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, flickr

I am a bit stumped here as the Flickr documentation makes mention of Collections and Galleries but nothing I've found related to Albums.

I am building a website in asp.net and want to load photos from a Flickr Album I have and after some time checking into the Collections and Galleries API with no luck I am hoping someone knows how to retrieve photos from a Flickr Album.

Here is what I have currently and it works well for photos from my photostream, but I've yet to figure out how to load Albums.

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using FlickrNet;

namespace MyWebSite.Core.Gateways
{
    public class FlickrGateway : IFlickrGateway
    {
        private readonly string _flickrApiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Flickr.ApiKey"];
        private readonly string _flickrApiSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Flickr.ApiSecret"];
        private readonly string _flickrApiUserId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Flickr.ApiUserId"];
        private readonly string _flickrPhotoSetId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Flickr.PhotoSetId"];

        private readonly Flickr _flickrApi;

        public FlickrGateway()
        {
            _flickrApi = new Flickr(_flickrApiKey, _flickrApiSecret) { InstanceCacheDisabled = true };

            if (OAuthToken == null) return;

            _flickrApi.OAuthAccessToken = OAuthToken.Token;
            _flickrApi.OAuthAccessTokenSecret = OAuthToken.TokenSecret;
        }

        public PhotoCollection GetPhotoStream()
        {
            return _flickrApi.PeopleGetPublicPhotos(_flickrApiUserId);
        }

        public PhotosetCollection GetPhotosetsList()
        {
            return _flickrApi.PhotosetsGetList(_flickrApiUserId);
        }

        public PhotosetPhotoCollection GetPhotoSet(string photoSetId)
        {
            return _flickrApi.PhotosetsGetPhotos(photoSetId);
        }

        public PhotosetPhotoCollection GetPhotoSet()
        {
            return _flickrApi.PhotosetsGetPhotos(_flickrPhotoSetId);
        }

        private static OAuthAccessToken OAuthToken
        {
            get
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["OAuthToken"] == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                var values = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["OAuthToken"].Values;
                return new OAuthAccessToken
                {
                    FullName = values["FullName"],
                    Token = values["Token"],
                    TokenSecret = values["TokenSecret"],
                    UserId = values["UserId"],
                    Username = values["Username"]
                };
            }
            set
            {
                var cookie = new HttpCookie("OAuthToken")
                {
                    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
                };
                cookie.Values["FullName"] = value.FullName;
                cookie.Values["Token"] = value.Token;
                cookie.Values["TokenSecret"] = value.TokenSecret;
                cookie.Values["UserId"] = value.UserId;
                cookie.Values["Username"] = value.Username;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get album photos you will need to call [flickr.photosets.getPhotos](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photosets.getPhotos.html) API method.

The corresponding method in .Net API is [`Flickr_Photosets.PhotosetsGetPhotos`](https://github.com/samjudson/flickr-net/blob/2ec93deb749f0b1af0a4df750e01d83817837590/FlickrNet/Flickr_Photosets.cs#L263).
As I can see you already have it: `GetPhotoSet`.

So all you need is just to pass your `albumId` as `photoSetId`.